# Querying laravel many-to-many relathionship

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 entities: page, category and page type. 
Page might be hidden, as well as category. (both have `hidden` column)
Page has page_type_id foreign key, so it belongs to page type entity.
Page and category has many-to-many relationship.

I need to query all pages which are not hidden and which are not linked to categories which are hidden. And page must also has some specific type.

I'm always struggling with Eloquent when it comes to a little bit complicated queries.
For example, I figured out how to check that a page has specific type:

```
$materials = Page::whereHas('type', function($query) {
    $query->where('type', 'material'); // A little bit confusing, type is a column name and also the relationship name, that's why I have type in whereHas and in where. Nevermind
);
```

I figured out how to eager load categories which are hidden or not using `with` and subquery.

But how to check that IF page has categories then they must not be hidden and IF page doesn't have categories then it doesn't but I have to get the page anyway?
`whereHas` won't load pages which don't have categories. And eager loading just loads or not categories but it has nothing to do with constraining pages based on `hidden` field in categories

Answer (score 0):

If you use `with()` rather than `whereHas()`, it will return the page even if it does not have a category.  Then in your sub-query, you select only categories that are not hidden.  This means it will only limit the categories returned, but not the pages.

This worked for me using the proper Laravel naming conventions for my models and tables...

```
$pages = Page::where('hidden', '0')
    ->with('categories', function($q)
    {
        $q->where('hidden', '0');
    })
    ->has('pageType')
    ->get();


foreach($pages as $page) {
    echo "Page Name: ".$page->name."<br />";
    echo "Page Type: ".$page->pageType->name."<br />";
    echo "Categories: <br /> <ul>";
    foreach($page->categories as $category) {
        echo "<li>".$category->name."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: To be honest I didn't get it. Yeah, I'll get pages with categories that are not hidden. I won't get pages to be filtrated. What I did - I got all pages and then used collection filter method, manually looping through each page and if its category is hidden I remove the page from collection

Comment: The first `where()` in the first line is filtering pages by hidden.

Comment: This is page hidden field. But also when a page belongs to hidden category the pages must be also excluded. And the part with eager categories loading only filters what categories will be connected to page, so if a category is hidden then it won't be within page object but the page object will be fetched from DB.

Comment: So if a page doesn't have any categories, you don't want that page to show up in your results?

Comment: If a page has categories which are hidden or if all categories not hidden but the page itself is hidden :) So I've already accomplished if by looping through page categories and checking if any of the categories are hidden. First I get all pages (with categories eager loading), which are not hidden, second I check all categories whether they're hidden or not